# My index on several columns is not used by query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize this query:

```
select id, entity_type
from tv_classified
where entity_type != 2
    and state = 0
    and dateExpiration < now();

54630 rows in set (1 min 0.42 sec)
```

So I added an index on these columns:

```
CREATE INDEX full_expiration_idx ON tv_classified (entity_type, state, dateExpiration)
```

The problem is that my query is still taking the same time, and ignore the index:

```
explain select id, entity_type from tv_classified where entity_type != 2 and state = 0 and dateExpiration < now();
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                                                    | key       | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tv_classified | ref  | dateExpiration_idx,entity_type_idx,state_idx,full_expiration_idx | state_idx | 2       | const | 1483498 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

It seems that Mysql does not use this index and prefer to use the index on the "state" field instead.

I know that I can use `use index(full_expiration_idx)` in the query (and it works fast 1min -> 0.5s) but I would like to understand why Mysql does not use him by himself.

Regards,

Comment: I don't know but I have a gut instinct about the `!=`. Can you tell us (out of interest) whether the index is used if you try it with `entity_type = 2` instead? I realise that's not what you want to do but it may confirm what I'm thinking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good call, the good index is chosen if i change the `!= 2`with `IN(0, 1, 3, 4)`, do you know why?

Comment: I think it's because you don't have a "known range" on the leftmost part of the key. If you imagine how the index data itself is structured, MySQL can't simply do a lookup on `entity_type`, then a lookup on the `state`s organised "underneath" it, then finally a range lookup on `dateExpiration` underneath that. It _could_ with `=`, but with your `!=` it instead has to look under pretty much every leaf of the `entity_type` tree (in fact, literally all of them except one) and so the benefit of an index lookup is not really there. It's decided that it's better off without it.

Comment: Massive disclaimer, though, I barely know what I'm talking about here. (And I don't have a solution for you, either!) Will be interesting to see what DBAs say about this.

Comment: can you show us the output of **select * from tv_classified procedure analyse();**

Comment: try to use a other index like **CREATE INDEX full_expiration2_idx ON tv_classified ( state, dateExpiration, entity_type);** that can better use the BTREE index

Answer (score 0):

You have created a composite key which  can be used with joining condition  where your 3 columns joined with 3 columns of another table. Since you are using filtered condition here so create 3 separate index for 3 columns.

Comment: A composite index is often _great_ for a condition chain, but here (and I think this is because the first condition is `!=`, not `=`), the OP must rely on the index merge optimisation, which indeed needs separate single-column indexes. I'm reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html and trying to refresh my memory.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't actually _know_ that IMO will help.